# How do you extract the first part of a cell?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a column of words that is preceded by a number.  I need to separate that number out into a separate cell so that I can easily compare it with another list that separates the number from the word.  I have included an image below so that you can see what it is I am trying to do:

[image]

I am using Excel 2007.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to post something using the Q&A-style to spare you the 12 minutes and 47 seconds of searching and experimenting I did while attempting to find an answer to this.

This formula here:

**=LEFT(B1,(FIND(" ",B1,1)-1))**

works quite well.  It should look like this when you finish:

[image]

For that, a fuller explanation, and related formulas, visit the following:

[**How to extract text before/after space or comma only in Excel?**](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1623-excel-extract-text-before-space.html#a1)